# How can I bind many event handlers to one event using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I'm experience strange behaviour with jQuery while trying to attach more than one event handler to a single event.

How would I bind two different event handlers, to the same event?

```
$(this).focus(function(){/*...*/});
$(this).focus(function(){/*...*/}); // replaces the previous one?
```

What am I missing?

#### Update

Do you know if it affects how event data is routed? It appears that adding a second event handler causes `eventObject.data` property to return `undefined`...?

---

#### Epilogue

The problem was somehow related to the way jQuery normalizes event handling and how the `eventObject` data property changed depending on routing, I had a delay timer at one point which read the property at a later time when it was undefined, I solved it by simply creating a local temporary for it.

```
obj.inputText.bind('blur', obj, function(e) {
    var div = e.data.div;
    setTimeout(function() { div.hide(); }, 333); // works!
    // setTimeout(function() { e.data.div.hide(); }, 333); // does not work
});
```

Comment: there are also namespaced events: http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events

Answer (score 3):

That does work.  I just double checked with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#FirstName").focus(function() {
    console.log("focus1");
  });

  $("#FirstName").focus(function() {
    console.log("focus2");
  });
});
```

And it does produce two console messages when the input field is focused.

Are you positive that both your handlers aren't running?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you create on "master" function that calls all needed handlers?

$(this).focus( function() { function1();function2();etc..... });

Answer (score 0):

This should theoretically work, try if all handlers are fired using:

```
$(this).focus( function() { alert('handler1'); });
$(this).focus( function() { alert('handler2'); });
$(this).focus();
```